# Code doesn't compile after all errors addressed for Rate Limitation Attempt

Tags: c#, error-handling, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

The end goal is to rate limit on the parameter which could be brute-forced to reveal sensitive information.

The first file is `DisplayMessage.cs` having this code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using BLL;
using DOL;

public partial class DisplayMessage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        //Security Fix for Session Fixation
        if (Session["User"] != null && Session["AuthToken"] != null
           && Request.Cookies["AuthToken"] != null)
        {
            if (!Session["AuthToken"].ToString().Equals(
                       Request.Cookies["AuthToken"].Value))
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
        }

        //if (!this.IsPostBack)
        //{
            BindFullMessage(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["MessageId"]));
        //}

            //Rate Limiting Security Vulnerability
            using (RateGate rateGate = new RateGate(2, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    rateGate.WaitToProceed();
                    BindFullMessage(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["MessageId"]));
                }

            } 

    }
    private void BindFullMessage(int MessageId)
    {
        CommonMethods commonMethod = new CommonMethods();
        lblFullMessage.Text = commonMethod.GetFullMessageByMessageId(MessageId);        
    }
}
```

The file `RateLim.cs` is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;





/// <summary>
/// Summary description for RateLim
/// </summary>

public class RateGate : IDisposable
{
    // Semaphore used to count and limit the number of occurrences per
    // unit time.
    private readonly System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;

    // Times (in millisecond ticks) at which the semaphore should be exited.
    private readonly System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<int> _exitTimes;

    // Timer used to trigger exiting the semaphore.
    private readonly Timer _exitTimer;

    // Whether this instance is disposed.
    private bool _isDisposed;

    /// <summary>
    /// Number of occurrences allowed per unit of time.
    /// </summary>
    public int Occurrences { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The length of the time unit, in milliseconds.
    /// </summary>
    public int TimeUnitMilliseconds { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a <see cref="RateGate"/> with a rate of <paramref name="occurrences"/> 
    /// per <paramref name="timeUnit"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="occurrences">Number of occurrences allowed per unit of time.</param>
    /// <param name="timeUnit">Length of the time unit.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
    /// If <paramref name="occurrences"/> or <paramref name="timeUnit"/> is negative.
    /// </exception>
    public RateGate(int occurrences, TimeSpan timeUnit)
    {
        // Check the arguments.
        if (occurrences <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("occurrences", "Number of occurrences must be a positive integer");
        if (timeUnit != timeUnit.Duration())
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("timeUnit", "Time unit must be a positive span of time");
        if (timeUnit >= TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(UInt32.MaxValue))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("timeUnit", "Time unit must be less than 2^32 milliseconds");

        Occurrences = occurrences;
        TimeUnitMilliseconds = (int)timeUnit.TotalMilliseconds;

        // Create the semaphore, with the number of occurrences as the maximum count.
        _semaphore = new System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim(Occurrences, Occurrences);

        // Create a queue to hold the semaphore exit times.
        _exitTimes = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<int>();

        // Create a timer to exit the semaphore. Use the time unit as the original
        // interval length because that's the earliest we will need to exit the semaphore.
        _exitTimer = new Timer(ExitTimerCallback, null, TimeUnitMilliseconds, -1);
    }

    // Callback for the exit timer that exits the semaphore based on exit times 
    // in the queue and then sets the timer for the nextexit time.
    private void ExitTimerCallback(object state)
    {
        // While there are exit times that are passed due still in the queue,
        // exit the semaphore and dequeue the exit time.
        int exitTime;
        while (_exitTimes.TryPeek(out exitTime)
                && unchecked(exitTime - Environment.TickCount) <= 0)
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
            _exitTimes.TryDequeue(out exitTime);
        }

        // Try to get the next exit time from the queue and compute
        // the time until the next check should take place. If the 
        // queue is empty, then no exit times will occur until at least
        // one time unit has passed.
        int timeUntilNextCheck;
        if (_exitTimes.TryPeek(out exitTime))
            timeUntilNextCheck = unchecked(exitTime - Environment.TickCount);
        else
            timeUntilNextCheck = TimeUnitMilliseconds;

        // Set the timer.
        _exitTimer.Change(timeUntilNextCheck, -1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Blocks the current thread until allowed to proceed or until the
    /// specified timeout elapses.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="millisecondsTimeout">Number of milliseconds to wait, or -1 to wait indefinitely.</param>
    /// <returns>true if the thread is allowed to proceed, or false if timed out</returns>
    public bool WaitToProceed(int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        // Check the arguments.
        if (millisecondsTimeout < -1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("millisecondsTimeout");

        CheckDisposed();

        // Block until we can enter the semaphore or until the timeout expires.
        var entered = _semaphore.Wait(millisecondsTimeout);

        // If we entered the semaphore, compute the corresponding exit time 
        // and add it to the queue.
        if (entered)
        {
            var timeToExit = unchecked(Environment.TickCount + TimeUnitMilliseconds);
            _exitTimes.Enqueue(timeToExit);
        }

        return entered;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Blocks the current thread until allowed to proceed or until the
    /// specified timeout elapses.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeout"></param>
    /// <returns>true if the thread is allowed to proceed, or false if timed out</returns>
    public bool WaitToProceed(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        return WaitToProceed((int)timeout.TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Blocks the current thread indefinitely until allowed to proceed.
    /// </summary>
    public void WaitToProceed()
    {
        WaitToProceed(Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    // Throws an ObjectDisposedException if this object is disposed.
    private void CheckDisposed()
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("RateGate is already disposed");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Releases unmanaged resources held by an instance of this class.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Releases unmanaged resources held by an instance of this class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isDisposing">Whether this object is being disposed.</param>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                // The semaphore and timer both implement IDisposable and 
                // therefore must be disposed.
                _semaphore.Dispose();
                _exitTimer.Dispose();

                _isDisposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the error what it gives:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Build Version + Settings Screenshots added for reference as asked by community

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of .Net Framework are you using?

Comment: .NET Framework 4
Build version :  4.0.0.0

Comment: Are you sure the version of the .Net Framework in the project where the `RateLim.cs` file is, is v4? Can you add a screenshot of the project settings?

Comment: Yes, it is. Plus, I've updated screenshot of settings + build version in OP, could you check how this problem comes up and 'why'? how do I resolve around this one?

Comment: Are you able to set your project to use a newer version of .Net Framework, even only temporarily to see if it helps?

Comment: It is not possible to change the .NET version. 
Could you please  point me to some alternative solutions (by providing suitable links), as our current effort seems counter-productive.
The rate limiting strategy remains unchanged. (as described by  your document).

Comment: I mean to change the version as a test to see if it fixes the issue, at least then we can have an idea of what the problem is.

Comment: Hi, tried to do the same, talked to dev teams and they complained it was the same error all over. You have the code files, I would appreciate if you could take a deeper look and compile on your system?

Comment: Well I don't have VS2010 to do a proper test. But spinning up VS2015 with a new Web Site project, setting it so .Net Framework 4 and then adding the `RateLim.cs` file, I hit compile and it works fine. [Like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RRPEv.png)

Comment: Anyway, I don't have a similar project to you so it's hard to compare. But your solution ha several projects. In which project is the RateLim.cs file? Is it in the main website project or in one of you class libraries?

Comment: It's in the main website project. It's not one of the class libraries. All the dev team is dependent on .Net 4.0 which is why, there are prod dependencies on it. Is there any alternative way to rate-limit that particular parameter?

Comment: What happens if you create a brand new project and add that code, does it compile in there?

Answer (score 0):

The [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.100).aspx) namespace is only available in .Net Framework v4.0 and above. Since it exists in `mscorlib`, it's not possible that you are missing that reference. The same goes for [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx). Possible solutions are:

- If possible, upgrade your project to the newer version of .Net.
- Find a library (Nuget?) that will help.
- Write your own concurrent collection class.

Comment: Hi Version info:

.NET Framework 4
Build version :  4.0.0.0